# Translating to english using word lists

Tags: python, replace

Say I have a list of item-colour pairs:

> Item1 red
>
> Item2 red_in_finnish
>
> Item3 red_in_polish
>
> Item4 blue_in_russian
>
> Item5 blue_in_estonian
>
> Item6 blue_in_polish

I need to translate all the colours in foreign languages to English:

> Item1 red
>
> Item2 red
>
> Item3 red
>
> Item4 blue
>
> Item5 blue
>
> Item6 blue

In my actual code, I have many more than two colours, and about a dozen different arrays containing all the foreign words for each colour. This is the current way I am performing the replacement:

```
red_words = ['red_in_finnish', 'red_in_polish']
blue_words = ['blue_in_russian', 'blue_in_estonian', 'blue_in_polish']

for word in red_words:
   if word in item_name:
      item_name = item_name.replace(word, "red")
```

The problem is that I do not know beforehand if each name contains any specific colour, so I need to check for all of them to make sure I replace everything.

Is there a smart way to do this? It would be perfect if it was possible to somehow map colours' foreign names to their English names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try using a dict

```
item_name = "hello my color is red_in_estonian"
dic = {
    "red_in_estonian"  :  "red",
    "red_in_german"    :  "red",
    "blue_in_estonian" :  "blue",
    "blue_in_german"   :  "blue",
}
for word in item_name.split(" "):
    try:
        translation = dic[word]
        item_name = item_name.replace(word, translation)

    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can do this by iterating over the `list` once, using a `dict`. An example:

```
red_words = {'red': 'red', # English
             'rojo': 'red', # Spanish
             'rot': 'red', # German
             'rouge': 'red' # French
            }

blue_words = {'blue': 'blue',
              'azul': 'blue',
              'blau': 'blue',
              'bleu': 'blue'
             }

# More colours here...

combined_translations = {**red_words, **blue_words}

data = [('blue_thing', 'bleu'), 
        ('also_blue_thing', 'azul'), 
        ('blueberry', 'blue'),
        ('fire engine', 'red'),
        ('blood', 'rouge'),
        ('tomato', 'rot')]

translated = [(item, combined_translations[colour]) for item, colour in data]

print(translated)
```

Output:

```
[('blue_thing', 'blue'), 
 ('also_blue_thing', 'blue'), 
 ('blueberry', 'blue'), 
 ('fire engine', 'red'), 
 ('blood', 'red'), 
 ('tomato', 'red')]
```

This will fail if, by some perverse chance, you have a word that is the same in two source languages, but each means a different colour in English.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Goslate (Free Google Translate API)](https://pypi.org/project/goslate/)

```
import goslate
gs = goslate.Goslate()

for word in words:
    print(gs.translate(word, 'en'))
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, but what if some colors are something like "steel gray" in polish, and I need them to be simply "gray" in english, so translate is not capable of doing this...